# Calling function parameters from main

Tags: java, oop

I want to take input from the user and show them on the screen with classes and functions, for example `elo.getHairColour`, according to the entered hair color. For example, it is like yellow but when calling from the main function, the parameters of my function should not be empty. How should I do?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        GetStrings();
        GetInt();
        Prınt(SetName(),GetInt()); // ->ıdk how to do here.
        
    
    }
    private static void Prınt(Object getStrings, Object getInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    public static void GetInt() {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter age: ");      
        int age = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter phonemodel-year: ");
        int model_year = scanner.nextInt();
        
    }
    public static int SetInt(int age) {
        return age;     
    }
    public static int SetModel_Year(int model_year) {
        return model_year;
    }
    public static String SetName(String name) {
        return name;
    }
    public static String SetSurName(String surname) {
        return surname;
    }
    public static String SetHName(String haircolor) {
        return haircolor;
    }
    public static String SetCName(String  city) {
        return city;
    }
    public static String SetPName(String phonecolour) {
        return phonecolour;
    }
    public static void GetStrings() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");     
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter surname: ");
        String surname = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter haircolor: ");
        String haircolor = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter city: ");
        String city = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter phone_colour: ");
        String phonecolour = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    public static void Prınt(String name,String surname,int age,String haircolor,String city, ElifPhone elophone,String phonecolour,int model_year)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ElifPhone iPhone_model = new ElifPhone(phonecolour,model_year);
        Elif elo = new Elif(name,surname,age,haircolor,city,iPhone_model);
        System.out.print(elo.getHair_colour());
    }
    public class Elif {
    
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;
    String hair_colour;
    String city;
     ElifPhone phone_model;
    
    public Elif(String iName,String iSurname,int iAge,String iHair_colour,String iCity,ElifPhone iPhone_model) {
        name = iName;
        surname = iSurname;
        age = iAge;
        hair_colour = iHair_colour;
        city = iCity;
        phone_model = iPhone_model;
    }
    
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getSurname() {return surname;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public String getHair_colour() {return hair_colour;}
    public String getCity() {return city;}
    public ElifPhone getPhone_model() {return phone_model;}

    public class ElifPhone {
    
    String phone_colour;
    int model_year;
    
    public ElifPhone(String iPhone_colour,int Model) {
        phone_colour = iPhone_colour;
        model_year = Model;
    }
    public String getPhoneColour() {
        return phone_colour;
    }
    public int getModel() {
        return model_year;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is how to make sure a command-line parameter is always present in `args`?

Comment: You should really stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase, so starting with lowercase and no underscores. Further, you should be consistent in the spelling you are using: colour and color are both fine, but not at the same time. At last, you are using an `ı` instead of `i`, which *may* confuse other people or even yourself.